# Creating a write-once file in HDFS

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs

I have a requirement that I am struggling with.

My goal is to create a history file of user processes and commands that is automatically captured in the background which creates a history file which is archived to Hadoop in real time. Upon connection termination of the logging system the file should not be able to be edited or removed by the user.

My current structure has my logging system piped to a hadoop fs -put -  command. The problem is that the file created is owned by the user, giving them the ability to remove that file.

Is there any way to have the directory level execute permissions override the user ownership permissions in HDFS? Is there another way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, you're looking for the `hdfs -chmod` or `-chown` command?

Comment: Normally that would work but because or how our user permissions are set up only super users can run chown.